# In R: from a matrix keep only last observation per row and set rest to NA

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

Please consider the following:

For a target value `target` I want to find the 'best' combination of numbers.

*You can think of a medicine with a target dose of 80mg but you only have 5mg, 20mg, 30mg, or 50mg at hand.*

The 'best' combination is the one where each number appears the least possible.

*For the medicine example this would be 50mg + 30mg, instead of 16 x 5mg.*

I managed a `while` loop that returns a matrix `mat`:

```r
library(dplyr)

target <- 80
combi <- c(5, 20, 30, 50)

#set empty matrix
mat <- matrix(combi, ncol = length(combi),dimnames = )

# while loop
while(target > 0){
        fills <- floor(target / combi)
        #fills[fills == 0] <- NA
        mgfills <- fills * combi
        target <- target - last(mgfills[mgfills > 0])
        target
        mat <- rbind(mat, fills)
        }

mat[mat == 0] <- NA
mat
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>          5   20   30   50
#> fills   16    4    2    1
#> fills    6    1    1   NA
```

Per row, the last number (exlcuding NA) is the number I am looking for. In a next step I want to fill a `data.frame` with the frequency needed for each value that should look like this:

```r
data.frame(combi = combi,
           freq = c(0, 0, 1, 1))

#>   combi freq
#> 1     5    0
#> 2    20    0
#> 3    30    1
#> 4    50    1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

My questions are:

- How can I go from a `matrix` in the example above to the desired `data.frame` in the same example?
- Is anyone aware of another way or package to compute these combinations?

Thank you very much!